# Using SpecFlow in Jetbrains Rider

Tags: c#, specflow, rider

Is there any way to use SpecFlow in Jetbrains Rider? I searched about it but I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: Could you tell which issues do you have with specflow? As far as I know it based on NUnit framework, so Rider can run tests out of the box. About generation, you can build a project and MsBuild regenerates spec files...

Comment: As you know  we need to install SpecFlow integration package first but there is no such an extension. https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207696605-Specflow-Add-on

Comment: For now it's not possible.. Hope we will publish SDK for plugins soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of March 2021 there is now a Rider Plugin for SpecFlow. You can find it at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15957-specflow-for-rider

---

<s>SpecFlow has two parts. The Visual Studio extension and the NuGet packages.

In the Visual Studio Extension are the intellisense, syntax highlighting and item templates included.
The NuGet package contains the runtime and the generators for the code behind files.</s>

The generation of the code behind files can be triggered by the Visual Studio extension (default behaviour) or at build time (http://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/). There are the generated coded tests located, that get then discovered by the unit test runner.

So if you use the MSBuild integration and work without intellisense and syntax highlighting, you should be already able to work with SpecFlow in Jetbrains Rider.